# I want to connect an ec2 instance which is in account A which should be able to access Bucket from both account A and another account B. How?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I saw the official documentation https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-instance-access-bucket/ which says to create role in both account and attach!
I had another solution which is create an IAM user in account B and grant it only S3 bucket permissions and config the EC2 Instance in Account B with that user. So if i do that will it work? and can the EC2 instance still access the S3 from the its account?

Comment: Technically possible or not, but it's a bad solution to rely on and maintain EC2 instance just to connect to S3 bucket. Cost ineffective solution as well.

Comment: If the instance in account A uses a role from account B "its account" now is basically B and no, it cannot access A's buckets unless the role explicitly grants access to the other buckets and the buckets allow cross account access. If you set up a bucket to allow cross account access and set up a role to grant the same then why not create both those things in account A directly?

Comment: So luk2302 can i do it using IAM user? Or should i go with Roles?

Comment: Always roles, users cannot do that. An EC2 instance can only assume roles / instance profiles, not users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your situation is:

- **Amazon EC2 instance** in Account A
- **Amazon S3 bucket** in Account A (`Bucket-A`)
- **Amazon S3 bucket** in Account B (`Bucket-B`)
- You would like the EC2 instance to be able to access both buckets

You should do the following:

- Create an **IAM Role** (`Role-A`) for the Amazon EC2 instance with:

  - Permission to access `Bucket-A`, *and*
  - Permission to access `Bucket-B`
- Add a **Bucket policy** to `Bucket-B` that permits access to the bucket from `Role-A` (This will grant "cross-account access")

That's it! The instance will be able to access `Bucket-A` due to permissions in the IAM Role, and it will be able to access `Bucket-B` due to permissions in both the IAM Role and the Bucket Policy.